# Setting default homepage using areas and Mvc route attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am using areas and attribute routing to set my url's for the site. My `AreaREgistration` is

```
  public class AreaNameAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
  {
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "AreaName";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
  }
```

In the controller i set the area

```
[RouteArea("AreaName",AreaPrefix="")]
```

Which allows me to set the `index` action to

```
[Route("Home")]
```

With the Url of

```
localhost:00000/Home
```

This works find throughout the site expect for the default root `localhost:00000/`

I get the error message

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'rememberMe' of non-nullable type

And it seems to want to set the default controller for that area to the `AccountController` which is sitting in the same area.

It i try and resolve this issue using the suggestions to similar questions in stackoverflow i add

```
context.MapRoute(
   "AreaName_default",
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new {controller="Home" ,action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

However if i do this then i get a new error message

> A route named 'AreaName_default' is already in the route collection.
>   Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name

Is there anyway to set the default root url to a specific action using route attributes and areas?

Answer (score 0):

I set the properties in the project , under the web tab to `Specific Page` equal to `Home`

Obviously there does not seem to be any major issue with the routing configuration, which was my primary concern using areas and route attributes